# How to correctly dereference a void pointer to class

Tags: c++

I have some problems with referencing void pointer to class.

I created a node "**index**" with a void data pointer which point to a class "**studentinfo**";
however, I encountered problems when I was trying to extract data member of the class "**studentinfo**".

The output error message is saying:

> "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

[image]

```cpp
int main()
{
    ...  
    Studentinfo *stu=new Studentinfo(id,name,score);  
    index=createNode(stu);  
    cout<<*static_cast <Studentinfo*> (index->dataPtr)->id; //Error ocurrs  
...  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - can you include all of your code in your question rather than as a separate link

Comment: Remove the `*` before `static_cast`.

Comment: Your static cast should contain template as follows static_cast<Studentinfo*>(index->dataPtr) and remove the dereference if you try to use the pointer operator(->)

Comment: I would recomend you use templates instead of `void*`'s.  Then you don't need to cast.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. StackOverflow has good enough syntax colouring, and we cannot copy/paste image to an online compiler to test it.

Answer (score 3):

`->` already does a deference. So `stu->id` is the same as `(*stu).id`.
In your code you are actually trying to deference `id`, which is an `int`. This is why you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator dereferences a pointer and accesses it's member. The `*` also does this. Because you've included both, you're actually trying to do it twice.

Probably the correction to the code you're looking for probably just needs to remove the extra `*` dereference. The error you're getting is because `static_cast <Studentinfo*> (index->dataPtr)->id` is already fully dereferenced and returning what you want, id. id is an int, so the `*` dereference operator is attempting to dereference an id(an int) which gives the error `invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

Now... with all that said I'm going to reiterate some of what your commentors have already said. This is extremely unsafe code. There's rarely a good reason to use void pointers or malloc in C++. Try to spend some more time learning about A: Constructors, B: How they interact with the `new` operator, and C: templates.

You will get code that is more readable and less error prone utilizing these techniques. Your main will be much more readable, as the statement that is currently giving you trouble can be simplified to `cout<<index->dataPrt->id` if your node uses templates, rather than a void pointer.